# Escaping Curly Brace in FitNesse Variable Declaraion

Tags: fitnesse

I want to store the following strings in FitNesse variables:

> !*< comment
>   {{{

and

> }}}
>   *!

Unfortunately, the fact that they contain curly braces "{}" is problematic for variable declaration in FitNesse, since I would have to declare them like this:

> !define IGNORE_START {!*< comment
>   {{{}
>   
>   !define IGNORE_END {}}}
>   *!}

The results of which are obviously not what I'm hoping for. Normally, I would expect to be able to escape the curly braces that I want to be included in the variable contents. However, searching Google and StackOverflow, I've not found the proper method for doing this. Some trial-and-error involving backslashes has also not led me to the solution.

If this is possible, can somebody please tell me how? If it's not possible, I'd also like to know so I can just accept it and move on.

Comment: On the advice of a commenter, I feel I should add that my goal is to simplify the creation of comment blocks by using more readable and memorable syntax. It's apparent, however, that it may not be possible to use variables this way. On the other hand, it's still valuable to know how escape sequences are expressed on FitNesse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put escape sequences in between `!-  -!`
e.g.

```
!define IGNORE_START {
!-!*< comment-!
!-{{{-! 
}

!define IGNORE_END {
!-}}}-!
!-*!-!
}

${IGNORE_START}
${IGNORE_END}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Unfortunately, in the process of escaping those sequences in order to save them in the variable, they also lose their meaning when I call the variable later. So rather than being interpreted by FitNesse as a comment block, it simply displays that escaped text in the page. I realize this is a logical consequence of escaping them, but I still had hoped it might work.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? It seems like you are trying to do comment out actual parts of a test and would like to use variables for that.  I don't think variables were ever intended to support that.  So maybe a little more about the problem you are trying to solve might help.

Comment: You are correct about my goal. I had hoped that it might work, since this type of "comment block" actually appears to be some kind of _syntax workaround_. I found it in some Yahoo Group, yet no mention of it anywhere in FitNesse documentation. I believe you're correct in that it just isn't possible to use variables this way.